how to know what platform you are on to install a wheel package?
I am trying to install ansible_pylibssh-1.2.2 on a offline version of redhat 8.Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.10 (Ootpa).
When I try to install this whl package, I keep making an error message:
python3 -m pip install --user --no-index --find-links . --upgrade ansible_pylibssh-1.2.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl

Error:
ansible_pylibssh-1.2.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

How do I know what package I need from this website? https://pypi.org/project/ansible-pylibssh/#files
I tried several different package names, but I keep getting the same error.

hi CPython 3.12 manylinux: glibc 2.28+ x86-64 what python --version do you have? What system are you running on? What glibc version do you have ldd --version? What architecture are you running on uname -m?

ldd (GNU libc) 2.28 is the glibc version. Python 3.12.3 x86_64 architecture


ldd (GNU libc) 2.28 is the glibc version. Python 3.12.3 x86_64 architecture

So use cp312-manylinux_2_28_x86_64

i tried this one. python3 -m pip install --user --no-index --find-links . --upgrade ansible_pylibssh-1.2.2-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl
ansible_pylibssh-1.2.2-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

try first python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
